# In the Eclipse debugger, what kind of changes can be "hot code replaced" into the running JVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jvm

In Eclipse, if you run a program under "Debug" you can make changes to the code, and most of the time it will take effect immediately.

Sometimes, though, it will not -- in which case it pops up a message, or says "(may be out of sync)" next to the threads in the Debug pane.

**What determines the kind of changes that can be hot-swapped?** I've noticed these changes usually fail:

- introducing new anonymous inner classes
- changing classes (renaming/adding/removing fields and methods) when the class is instantiated
- adding a try-catch block

but sometimes it seems to be almost random. What is the logic behind determining whether code can be replaced or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Method statements (procedural code) work. Everything related to adding, removing or changing class schemas does not work. So no modifying inheritances, fields, extracting methods, changing signatures etc.

Usually hot-swapping method statements does not work if you are doing anything forbidden at the same time. Then the hot-swapping connection is "broken", so to say.

One thing I do not know for sure is anonymous classes. Have never tried that in connection with hot-swapping.

Edit: The guys over there at zeroturnaround have compiled a list in their features section what the jvm debugger can not do out of the box to promote their product: http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/features/ . Whether you like the tool or not, the list reflects my experience.