# Java cache issue ? debugger in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I use eclipse debugger to step through debug points.
My problem is that when i update the java code for server, the
eclipse doesnt take the updated code. 
Also the break points seem to appear from previous code. 
The break points do not work...Example, sometimes, the debugger steps through an empty white line, instead of going to next statement.
Seems to me like an update issue for java cache.

I am not sure as to how to avoid it.
I usually go with clean and build.
But, is there a easier way to just  hot deploy the code and make all of it work properly without
rebuilding the entire project?

OR another quick question, can we atleast automate java cache clean mechanism to run everytime in windows?

#

My question was, even when I refresh the project/ when I clean & build, sometimes in Eclipse the old code is taken instead of a new code. 
I am not sure why this happens, only when I clear the java cache, this issue dissapers and I have to redeploy my jboss.

My question to you guys was, is there a way to avoid this??
I am using Flex builder( built on eclipse) for development.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948912/in-the-eclipse-debugger-what-kind-of-changes-can-be-hot-code-replaced-into-th

Comment: where do you get the updated code from? Someone else deploying changes? Usually the problem is the other way around, I have updated the code in eclipse and the server still has old code.

Comment: To elaborate on @Roger s comment: is the location where the code added to the 'User Entries' of the Classpath for your debug configuration?

Comment: "I have updated the code in eclipse and the server still has old code"...I have the same issue. Not sure how to resolve it.Is there a faster way to rebuild the project (EAR file) rather than clean and build and make it work. Since the incremental build sometimes does not take the previous code...Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to link your server project src folder to your current project.

This could be done as follows:

Right click on the current project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Source --> Link Source --> Browse, then locate your server project src. Finally change the Folder name field as you wish.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Build > Right click on the project > Refresh > On the Server view it should show it picked up a change > debug on the server