# Hot code replace on classes containing nested classes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hotswap

I'm trying to dynamically apply code changes to a Java application I'm debugging using Eclipse.
Everything works as expected for all classes except one.
After doing any minor change and saving it, I get an error message, saying  `Hot Code Replace Failed - add method not implemented`.

So far I found out that in contrast to others, my problematic class contains (anonymous and explicit) nested classes.
As a consequence, building my application results in more than one `.class` file; one for the main class and an additional one for each inner class.
I highly suspect this as the reason behind the failing code replace attempt.

*TL;DR:* **Is there any way to do hot code replacing on classes containing inner/nested classes?**

Comment: Hot code replace is not a normal feature. With nested classes classes have to be patched in a group. "Not yet implemented" thingy

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Hotswap Agent](http://www.hotswapagent.org/):

- Framework support - Spring, Hibernate, Logback, Jetty, Tomcat, JSF, ...
- Documentation how to setup DCEVM and precompiled binaries for Java 1.7, 1.8
- Load classes/subclasses and resources from various location (allow reload of classes from dependent project]
- Open source and free

Answer (score -1):

You can't do hot code replace if you you change the class scheme

see [In the Eclipse debugger, what kind of changes can be "hot code replaced" into the running JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948912/in-the-eclipse-debugger-what-kind-of-changes-can-be-hot-code-replaced-into-th)

Comment: I'm not chaning the class scheme. As I said in my answer, it fails for any minor change, even adding or removing some whitespace.

Comment: Because it's an nested class, it should regenerate synthetic method, therefore changing its scheme i guess